# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-zx \ln (zx)}{-x \ln x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Title says it all. How can I evaluate the limit provided as:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-zx \ln (zx)}{-x \ln x}
\end{equation}

I do know that it is equal to $z$. What I do not know is why.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all guys,I should have seen it earlier! Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-zx \ln (zx)}{-x \ln x}&=z\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{ \ln (zx)}{ \ln x}\\
&=z\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{ \frac{z}{zx}}{ \frac1x}\\
&=z
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I am blind!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**
$$
\frac{-zx\log(zx)}{-x\log x}
=z\frac{\log z+\log x}{\log x}
=z\left[\frac{\log z}{\log x}+1\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-zx \ln (zx)}{-x \ln x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-zx \ln (z)-zx\ln(x)}{-x \ln x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{z(-x \ln (z)-x\ln(x))}{-x \ln x}  = \lim_{x \to 0^+}{z\left({ \ln (z) \over  \ln (x)}+1\right)} = z
$$

since $\lim_{x \to 0+} \ln(x) = -\infty$, thus $\lim_{x \to 0+} {\ln(z) \over\ln(x)} = 0$